# How to monitor ubuntu server resources consumption history

Tags: performance-monitoring, ubuntu-20.04

I'm working with a new web application installed on Ubuntu 20.04 server.
The web application is still in testing status and I need to check if the machine resources are enought during the day.

How can I easily monitor resources consumption history to check periodically peeks during the day?

Server doesn't have GUI.

I have used htop for instant consumption checks, but I cannot log all the information with htop.

Comment: If you want something very simple sysstat (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sysstat&searchon=names&suite=focal&section=all) may suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I  normally try to include test servers in our regular monitoring, but silenced so whomever is on pager duty  won't get alerts.

That will hopefully also teach us if there are any gaps in the monitoring that we'd need to address before the application is released to production and can  provide the kind of baseline, tuning and sizing info that you appear to be looking for.

If you don't have access to ops monitoring (yet) and setting up one of the many tools listed in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems
is overkill:

Consider enrolling with one of the many cloud based  monitoring / application performance analysis  providers. Many require only a single easily configured agent and offer a free (trial) tier that can be enough to collect sufficient data points  for analysis, insights and provide nice web based GUI. There are alternatives in `New Relic, Dynatrcace, Datadog, AppDynamics` and many others.